# Pyside2 how to get mouse position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, pyside2

I want to get mouse position in my pyside2 application.(not desktop mouse position that QCursor gives) and I tried two way. Bellow is my code.

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Palette(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos()) # always return (0,0)
        print(QtWidgets.QWidget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))) #makes parameter type error
        print(QtWidgets.QWidget.mapToGlobal(QtWidgets.QWidget))  # makes  parameter type error
        print(QtWidgets.QWidget.mapToGlobal(QtWidgets.QWidget.pos()))  # makes parameter type error

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        palette = Palette(self)
        view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(palette, self)
        view.resize(500, 500)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(500, 500)
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I very wonder how i can get my mouse pos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand you want to get the position on the window if you click anywhere in a widget.

To solve the problem, the logic is as follows:

- Get the mouse position with respect to the widget
- Convert that position to a global position, that is, with respect to the screen.
- Convert that global position to a position relative to the window.

For the first step if `mousePressEvent()` is used, `event.pos()` returns the position relative to the widget.

For the second step you must convert that position relative to the widget to global with `mapToGlobal()`.

And for the third step `mapFromGlobal()` of window is used.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    p = event.pos() # relative to widget
    gp = self.mapToGlobal(p) # relative to screen
    rw = self.window().mapFromGlobal(gp) # relative to window
    print("position relative to window: ", rw)
    super(Widget, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

---

**Update:**

The `QGraphicsScene` is not a widget, it is not a visual element, although it is part of the representation of a visual element: the `QGraphicsView`. For you to understand I will explain you with an analogy, let's say that there is a cameraman recording a scene, in that example the `QGraphicsScene` is the scene and the `QGraphicsView` is what the camera records, that is, it shows a piece of the `QGraphicsScene`, so there could be another cameraman recording the scene from another point, so it would show the same scene from another perspective, so the position of the scene depends on the camera, so if your current question would be equivalent to saying which is the position of the point P respect to the camera i-th, and that from the scene is impossible, you should get it from the camera.

So in conclusion you should not use QGraphicsScene but QGraphicsView, the following solutions implement the same logic using 2 different methods:

**1. Creating a custom class of QGraphicsView:**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        p = event.pos() # relative to widget
        gp = self.mapToGlobal(p) # relative to screen
        rw = self.window().mapFromGlobal(gp) # relative to window
        print("position relative to window: ", rw)
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        view = GraphicsView(scene, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(500, 500)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**2. Using eventfilter:**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._view)
        self._view.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self._view and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            p = event.pos() # relative to widget
            gp = self.mapToGlobal(p) # relative to screen
            rw = self.window().mapFromGlobal(gp) # relative to window
            print("position relative to window: ", rw)
        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.resize(500, 500)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On the other hand `mapToGlobal()` is a method that must be called by an instance, when you use `QtWidgets.QWidget.mapToGlobal()` there is no instance, my question is, what widget do you have the position? the position you have with respect to self, so you must use `self.mapToGlobal()` , that works for the objects belonging to a class that inherit from `QWidget` as `QGraphicsView`, but not in `QGraphicsScene` since it does not inherit from `QWidget`, it is not a widget as indicated in the lines above.

Comment: Thank you!! As your saying I misunderstand between Scene and View. I am tried to draw a rectangular at mouse position. Thanks for your solution I solved the problem! Thank you for very kind response!

Answer (score 1):

I have recently found a more universal way of getting the cursor position, if you don't want to go through sub classing and events.

```
# get cursor position
cursor_position = QtGui.QCursor.pos()

print cursor_position
### Returns PySide2.QtCore.QPoint(3289, 296)
```